# Applying Resharper Naming Rules in InspectCode

Tags: command-line, resharper, settings, code-inspection

I am evaluating Resharper. Their default naming rules are different from our internal rules, so I changed some settings and also exported them into MySolution.sln.DotSettings. And yes, I can see them there, e.g.

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpNaming/PredefinedNamingRules/=Parameters/@EntryIndexedValue">&lt;Policy Inspect="True" Prefix="_" Suffix="" Style="aaBb" /&gt;</s:String>
```

Next, I run Inspect code on a command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CommandLineTools\InspectCode.exe" MySolution.sln /o=Resharper.Result.xml
```

When I do that on my local computer (Resharper Ultimate Test version is installed), the rules are correctly observed and a 44 kB result file is generated.

When I run it on a different machine (only CommandLineTools installed), the naming rules are ignored, and a 73 kB result file is generated.

Some other rules of the .DotSettings file seem to be applied, because after deleting it, a 86 kB result file is generated.

With the /no-swea parameter, the file gets down to 23 kB (on my machine 25 kB), the naming rules are applied, but several checks are not performed, e.g. "VirtualMemberNeverOverriden.Global", "UnusedMember.Global", etc., hence this is not a proper solution.

How can I make InspectCode apply all the rules of the settings file?

Edit:
Copying those rules into %appdata%\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage does not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Resharper Ultimate did not help either.
Only after installing Visual Studio 2013 on the other machine (VS2013 is installed on my computer, on the other computer VS2015 Community Edition with an expired license is already present), and adding the /toolset=12.0 parameter, consistent results are obtained. The command line is now

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CommandLineTools\InspectCode.exe" /o=Resharper.Result.xml /toolset=12.0 MySolution.sln
```